# How linux io_uring store pointers to cqe buffers of processes?

Tags: data-structures, linux-kernel, io-uring

As I understand in io_uring system Linux must store pointers to processes cq to know where to put answers to submissions of that processes.  In what structure and what size of that structure or it is dynamical?

Comment: You mean completion queue cq, not event cqe. It's in io_rings.